# Wrapping TD contents of datatable inside a span tag

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatable, tooltip

am using data table and loading data from db using Ajax.  the data is getting loaded properly.  but i want to enclose each context of TD inside a span tag like below

```
<td><span>cell content</span></td>
```

currently the output is coming as

```
<td>cell content</td>
```

how do i do this?  am using datatable and bootstrap.

Comment: If you have the reference to the tds then `$tds.wrapInner('<span />')`

Comment: the data table part will depend upon how you are loading the data table

Comment: am getting the data via Ajax call.  the controller returns List<List<string>> and somehow it is binded to the datatable via client side code.

Answer (score 0):

add this and it worked

```
var id;
fnRender: function (oObj) {id = oObj.aData[0]
                       return '<span title="' + id + '">' + oObj.aData[0] + '</span>';
    }
```